# Display problem facing when try to write data/text into minicom(ttyUSB0) from a file

Tags: serial-port, ubuntu-22.04, minicom

I am trying to write data from a input.txt [image: file screenshot]to minicom using an buffer, the problem is buffer is taking the data and I think it is even sending to minicom(ttyUSB0) and the lines getting jumbled,[image: minicom screenshot]

can you please help me with it.

The data is getting transffered for sure but it is not displaying correctly

Comment: How is this related to programming and the C language you have tagged? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: As a hint: Newline versus Carriage return *and* newline.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66921013/17592432 this link helped me . Thanks

Comment: fyi - [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Aside from that: this question is off-topic here - it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By enabling the carriage return in the screen and keyword configuration can solve this problem.

screen and keyword >> press "T" which enables carriage return